# Return Path as a String

Tags: java, string, function, path, return

i would like to check a combobox, if the `Layer` is `"LVS"` or `"PRJ"`. If one of these is selected, i want to return a Path as a `String`, but the function always return `"null"`. Can someone help me maybe?

```
private String getGroovyPath(MyTitleAreaDialog dialog)
{
    String LayerLVS = "lvs/dev/scripts/123/aderf/de/lock/clt/Simplescript.groovy";
    String LayerPRJ = "prj/dev/scripts/123/aderf/de/lock/clt/Simplescript.groovy"";

    if(dialog.getLayer() == "LVS")
    {
        return LayerLVS;
    }
    else if(dialog.getLayer() == "PRJ")
    {
        return LayerPRJ;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: are you sure that **dialog.getLayer()** get the value **"LVP" or "PRJ"**

Comment: yeah, its a Combobox and i only set the Defaults to "LVS" and "PRJ"

Answer (score 0):

in java you should use `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` function to compare two string. try code bellow:

```
private String getGroovyPath(MyTitleAreaDialog dialog)
{
String LayerLVS =     "lvs/dev/scripts/123/aderf/de/lock/clt/Simplescript.groovy";
String LayerPRJ = "prj/dev/scripts/123/aderf/de/lock/clt/Simplescript.groovy"";

if(dialog.getLayer().equalsIgnoreCase("LVS"))
{
    return LayerLVS;
}
else if(dialog.getLayer().equalsIgnoreCase("PRJ"))
{
    return LayerPRJ;
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks mate! that worked for me! Have a nice day! :-)